# How do I input an unknown number of digits with scanf in C?

Tags: c

So I was trying to work a problem out, my problem is :
First I have an input `n` which determines how many test cases I have. Suppose `n =2:` then the next input is `m` - which is how many numbers are there in the following sequence.  Suppose `m =4 :`

The next input is a sequence example :  `1 0 3 5`. Next I get another `m` and another sequence and so on. So I need to input `m` and its sequence `n` times....I couldn't do that with `scanf`.

Take a look at the [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CRAN02) to understand what I mean.

Comment: You take a string and then parse it with a loop.

Comment: Tip: Rather than post relevant code someplace else, post it here.  Questions without code here attract down-votes and closure.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you don't get what you should be doing here. You will get number of test cases first and then you will do the work for each of the test cases.

```
if(scanf("%d",&n)==1){
  while(n--){
    ..
    if( scanf("%d",&m) != 1){
       /* handle error */
    }
    ..
    for(size_t i = 0; i<m; i++){
      if( scanf("%d",&a[i])!= 1){
         /* handle error */
      }
    }
    ..
    // do work with array a[]
  }

}
```

Giving all input at once doesn't mean that you have to take all of them together. The method I have shown above is the usual way these problems are handled.

Here we are basically processing the inputs chunk by chunk. Initially we get the number of test cases and then we are running a `while` loop exactly `n` number of times. In each iteration we first then get the input `m` and then process `m` numbers of the sequence after we get the input.

I have here checked the returned value of `scanf` in case there is any error for which `scanf` couldn't parse an `int` and assign it to corresponding variable whose address has been passed to `scanf` then we will likely face an error case and we will handle it (Most probably by showing a message and exiting from the code). In case of `scanf` - it will return the number of successful items it scanned and assigned. We are expecting to `scan` 1 number at each call and assign it to the variable whose address has been passed. That is what is being done here. In case it is successful it will return `1`.

Comment: okay i know i am asking a lot of you right now...but this is really urgent and important to me right now...i am not that good in C...so could you please write the full code for the problem and maybe do comments so i can understand, i had a test in class for this today and i'll be having more tomorow i really need to understand this one so i can get better at the others....i will really greatful

Comment: @IlyesHamrouni.: Nope...I am afraid I can't do that. Show your effort - try harder, you can do it.

Comment: man....i was trying from 8am and now its 6pm...okay...could you at least explain more the code you wrote i didn't really understand it

Comment: @IlyesHamrouni.: Sure i can explain the part I wrote here. wait a sec.

Comment: @IlyesHamrouni.: I added an explanation of what I did..please read and hey all the best for the problem.

Comment: thanks so much man.

Comment: @IlyesHamrouni "trying from 8am and now its 6pm" is not that long. It reminds me of coding from "6pm to 8am" (without Internet to bail me out).